# Running Excel macro from Windows PowerShell script

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I want to run below Excel macro from Windows PowerShell script.

```vb
Public Sub LogInformation()
   Dim strFile_Path As String
   strFile_Path = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName & ".txt"
   Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
   Write #1, "message As String" & "   : Logged at " & Now
   Close #1
End Sub
```

My PowerShell

```
 #Call the application
 $excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
 #Now we select the file and path 
 $excelFile = Get-ChildItem -Path "..\McroWPSS.xlsm"
 #The next variable speeds the script up by not calling the comobject as    often
$app = $excel.Application

#Now we open the Excel file and activate the macro enabled content
$workbook = $app.workbooks.open($excelfile)

#The next command makes Excel visible
$app.Visible = $false
$workbook.Activate()

 #Now we run all the Macros that need to be run.
  $app.Run("LogInformation")

 #Now we save the workbook in the standard daily format and the close Excel
$workbook.save()
$workbook.close()

 $excel.quit()
```

When I run my PowerShell script I get

> Exception calling "Run" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot run the macro 'Workbook_Open'. The macro may not be available in 
>   this workbook or all macros may be disabled."
>   At D:\Powershell\practice\MacroRun.ps1:16 char:2
>   +  $app.Run("Workbook_Open")
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException
>
> Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "'McroWPSS.xlsm' is read-only. To save a copy, click OK, then give the 
>   workbook a new name in the Save As dialog box."
>   At D:\Powershell\practice\MacroRun.ps1:19 char:2
>   +  $workbook.save()
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Comment: The first line of the error describes the reason: either you haven't enabled the macros explicitly via powershell cmd or there isn't any macros that's what comes to my mind for now

Comment: After this `$workbook = $app.workbooks.open($excelfile)` where did you enable the macro content ? [See This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907650/enable-macros-via-powershell) for more info.

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your script - what macro are you trying to run, how is it declared, and what module is it in?

Comment: Thanks you very much. I am using excel 2010. My Macros are in  work book level General. And Powershell windows powwershell script in windows 7.  powershell.ps1

Answer (score 0):

You can control the macro enabled/disbaled via the registry. That's how I got mine to run.

Enable

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name AccessVBOM -PropertyType DWORD  -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name VBAWarnings -PropertyType DWORD  -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
```

Disable (after running macro)

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name AccessVBOM -PropertyType DWORD  -Value 0 -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name VBAWarnings -PropertyType DWORD  -Value 0 -Force | Out-Null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still i am getting the same.

Comment: Are you able to manually open that node in the registry to check what the values are set to? [This page](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/diana_tudor/2014/12/02/microsoft-project-how-to-control-macro-settings-using-registry-keys/) discusses macro security settings. I am assuming the first part of the error message is incorrect adn the `LogInformation` macro is part fo the workbook you are opening (and not the Personal.XLSB or some other workbook). Edit: Also, I believe you have to run Powershell as admin to make registry changes.

Comment: Not in front of my computer to test, what if you use explicit path/filename instead of variable in the workbooks.open. Pretty sure I've had this issue and found solution on this site. Path/filename might require quoting. My guess is the workbook isn't getting opened in first place.