# Error when importing .bas file into Excel with PowerShell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I wrote a simple PowerShell script that exports VBA modules for version control. Now I'm trying to do the opposite operation, I want to import the extracted VBA modules into an Excel file, save it as macro-enabled and use the macros.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$PSScriptRoot\$filepath")
$macros = Get-ChildItem -Path .\BASscripts -File
foreach ($macro in $macros) {
    $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import($macro)
}
$workbook.SaveAs($filepath, 52)

$excel.Workbooks.Close()
$excel.Quit()
```

I keep getting the following error.

```
OperationStopped: C:\Users\<user>\source\repos\vba\import.ps1:18
Line |
  18 |      $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import($macro)
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | 'C:\Users\<user>\source\repos\vba\BASscripts\<macro_name>.bas' could not be loaded.
```

Manually exporting and importing the macros works just fine, but I've diffed the files (manual export and programmatic export) and they are identical.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you set the option for "Trust access to the VBA project object model" within the Trust Center > Macro settings?

Comment: I did, followed this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35897244/5607403)

Comment: The `.Import()` method requires a **string** (the full path to the file). You are feeding it a FileInfo **object**. Try `$workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import($macro.FullName)`

Answer (score 0):

[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s comment is in fact the solution to my problem. Thank you.

Turns out `$workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import` takes a string to the full path of the `.bas` macro file. I was passing it a FileInfo Object.

Changing the code to the following, allows me to programmatically import all my macros into an Excel workbook of choice.

```
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$PSScriptRoot\$filepath")
$macros = Get-ChildItem -Path .\BASscripts -File
foreach ($macro in $macros) {
    $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import($macro.FullName) | Out-Null
}
```